# How to get the date of the last comment a user created in a topic

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Topic model, Comment Model and a User model. They each have associations with each other. I want to see the date of the last comment that was commented in a uniq topic. I was thinking something like this would work but it just shows the last comment created by a user and not for each topic.

```
  = topic.user.comments.last.created_at.strftime("%b, %d, %Y")

  %table.table
            %thead
                %tr
                    %th Topic
                    %th Users
                    %th Replies
                    %th Activity
            - @topics.each do |topic|
                %tbody
                    %tr
                        %td{:width => "800"}
                            = link_to topic.title, topic_path(topic)
                        %td{:width => "200"}
                            .users-image
                                - topic.comments.uniq(&:user_id).each do |comment|
                                    = image_tag(comment.user.avatar.url(:thumb))
                        %td{:width => "80"}
                            .comments
                                = topic.comments.count
                        %td{:width => "80"}
                            .activity
                                =# topic.user.comments.last.created_at.strftime("%b, %d, %Y")
```

Comments table

```
create_table "comments", force: :cascade do |t|
 t.string   "commentable_type"
 t.integer  "commentable_id"
 t.integer  "user_id"
 t.text     "body"
 t.datetime "created_at",       null: false
 t.datetime "updated_at",       null: false
end
```

Comment: Have you tried querying the topics model for the last comment instead of the user model? If you do something at the bottem like `topic.user.comments.last` you'll grab the last comment that the user made but  if a topic has many comments you could just search for the topic with `topic = Topic.find(id)` and then do `topic.comments.last`. If there is a created_at table for the comment, it should grab the last one.

Comment: First thing: a lot of this stuff should be abstracted out to a model. That will allow you to run tests, which will help you to figure out what you're doing wrong faster. Second: once you've done that, you should also look up what the 'delegate' method is in rails and why you should use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use

```
topic.comments.last.created_at.strftime("%b, %d, %Y")
```

will get the last comment date of the topic.

Comment: I tried that but i get ` undefined method created_at' for nil:NilClass ` .

Comment: Seems like the `topic` doesn't have any comments. Please try to use `topic.comments.last.created_at.strftime("%b, %d, %Y") unless topic.comments.empty?`

Comment: That's the second time that i forget to add something like that. Thanks for the help.